# How to looping data in multiple

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I have a script looping, but I want my ads showing only every fourth time.

For example :

> schools-1
>
> schools-2
>
> schools-3
>
> schools-4
>
> **ads-1**
>
> schools-5
>
> schools-6
>
> schools-7
>
> schools-8
>
> **ads-2**

This is my script

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$i=0;
$data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school))
{
    if($i%4==0)
    { 
          $data_ads=mysql_query("select * from ads");
          while ($ads =mysql_fetch_object($data_ads)){    
        echo "<br/><a href='<?php echo $ads->link ?>'><img src='images/ads/<?php echo $ads->images_ads ?>' alt=''></a><br/>";
          }
    }
    echo $school->name_school . "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```

But when I'm running the script, the result looks like this:

> schools-1
>
> schools-2
>
> schools-3
>
> schools-4
>
> **ads-1**
>
> **ads-2**
>
> schools-5
>
> schools-6
>
> schools-7
>
> schools-8
>
> **ads-1**
>
> **ads-2**

Comment: either prebuild an array structure to create that way, or use an offset inside the second query

Comment: can you give me example, i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick-fix that will iterate through all your ads once, and it will repeat the ads if `$number_of_schools*4>$number_of_ads`

```
<?php
include "connection.php";
$ads=NULL;
$data_ads=NULL;
$i=0;
$data_school=mysql_query("select * from school");
while ($school=mysql_fetch_object($data_school))
{
    if($i%4==0)
    { 
          if (!$ads)
             {$data_ads=mysql_query("select * from ads");}
          $ads =mysql_fetch_object($data_ads);    
        echo "<br/><a href='<?php echo $ads->link ?>'><img src='images/ads/<?php echo $ads->images_ads ?>' alt=''></a><br/>";
    }
    echo $school->name_school . "<br/>";
    $i++;
}
?>
```